# How to create a function in MATLAB that gives out a varying number of outputs?

Tags: matlab, function

I want to modify a simple function that solves quadratics so that if there is a repeated root it will only output one of them. I have named x1, x2 as my two outputs - how do I 'supress' one of them in the case of a repeated root?

I've tried x1=x2= -b/(2*a) but it comes up with the error 'The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.' Why doesn't this work? And how can i get it to work?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Please edit your question to give us some more information: Provide an example of how you want to call the function and what the expected results should be in case of 2 roots and only one root. As @Ratbert mentions in his answer there are many ways to do it...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this. The best is probably to output a single variable, an array or a cell, that contain a variable number of elements corresponding to your roots.

In your case this gives something like:

```
function out = myfunction(...)

...

if x1==x2
    out = x1
else
    out = [x1 x2];
end
```

You can of course modify it to take also into account the cases where there is no solution.

Also, you should know that there exists a built-in function that finds all polynomial roots for you: it is [`roots`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html).

Best,